# Add markers to google maps refresh

Tags: java, android

I load some markers to google maps via AsyncTask.

however, when the markers loading is finish, i need to click on the zoom button inorder that the map will show the markers ( i guess it is needed to refreshing the map)

is there any method for refreshing the google maps?or another solution?

i use the variable

```
private static GoogleMap map;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `map.invalidate()` will help you to refresh because it cause a redraw.
See..

- [Redraw/refresh Itemizedoverlay? (android/google maps api)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014987/redraw-refresh-itemizedoverlay-android-google-maps-api)
- [How to refresh Google map.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103780/how-to-refresh-google-map)

Comment: it wrote me that GoogleMap variable doesnt have method named "invalidate"

Comment: Which version of android map api you are using? It works well in API V2.See an example here..http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-with-gps-and-locationmanager-in-android/

Comment: hi, i get the GoogleMap variable via : "        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sale_page_map)).getMap();
"   how can i get the mapView? i declared a fragment with "class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"" in the layout..thanks alot

Comment: After studying on this topic,sorry to say you,map.invalidate() works only previous versions of Map Api,that not for v2.At present,Google Map Api v2 doesn't support refresh features.So the possible solution will be,you can use previous map api or you can use moveCamera() or animateCamera() of current api.How to use them you can find in..http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/